# On hover background image expand

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, jquery-hover

I have an image overlaying another image and I would like the behind image to expand on hover. The thing is I cant make behind image (back ground image) expand evenly. it grows out to the right and up.

```
$(".wooll").hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        'height': $(this).height() * 1.8,
        'width' : $(this).width() * 1.8
    });
},function() {
   $(this).animate({
        'height': $(this).height() / 1.8,
        'width' : $(this).width() / 1.8
    });
});
```

**How do I position it central in the parent div to make it expand evenly?**

```
<div id="woolley-expand">

<img class="wooll" style="text-align: center; position: absolute; bottom: 0px;" src="/images/component-bottle-big.png" width="60" height="117" />
<img src="/images/free-spray-text.png" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;"/>
</div>

#woolley-expand {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can see what you've got, and what you're working with?

Comment: @david http://jsfiddle.net/AVyQc/1/

Comment: @DavidThomas did you receive my demo? Also I need the expansion to be activated when both images are hovered. (Note, only the one image expands when both are hovered)